# Jump if touching the ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sphere which jumps after I touch the screen. In my previous code, it was jumping infinite time, but in the current code, it is jumping only once. I want the sphere to jump every time I touch the screen, but the main issue is, I want it to jump only when it is on the ground. I tried this...

```
public float speed;
public Rigidbody rb;
private bool thrown ;



void Start() 
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update() 
{
    if (
        !thrown && (
            (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended ) ||
            Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) )
    )
    {
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        rb.AddForce (new Vector3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f));
        thrown = true ;

    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{ 
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("player")) 
    {
        thrown = true;
    }
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong in ontriggerEnter or may be somewhere else. Please help me with it.

Comment: On `OnTriggerEnter`, `thrown = true;` shouldn't be `thrown = false;`?

Comment: That's not working either.

Comment: You also need to set `thrown` to `false` in the `OnCollisionExit` function. See duplicate for more info. By the way, stop disabling isKinematic each time you press a button